# Numerical solution of differential equation with DiracDelta fit boundary condition at zero poorly

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions, boundary-condition-at-infinity, singularity

I need to solve: $x^2y''(x)+(2x+1)y'(x)-x^2\omega^2y(x)=\frac{-\omega^2\delta(x-x_0)}{4\pi},x\in[0,\infty)$ with boundary conditions:$y(0)=1,\ y(\infty)=0$ , $\omega$ is a function of this form: `\[Omega][t_]:=(Sqrt[282226247569711/87] E^(87/50))/(7968600Pi^(3/2) t^(153252039/6408706520))`$ t\in[0,\infty)$, $x_0$ - constant(for example, 0.3).
I tried this code to solve it:

```
x0=0.3;
\[Omega][t_]:=(Sqrt[282226247569711/87] E^(87/50))/(7968600Pi^(3/2) t^(153252039/6408706520));

sol = With[{\[CurlyEpsilon] = 1/1000}, 
   ParametricNDSolveValue[{(x^2)y''[x] + (2 x + 1)y'[x] - (x^2)(\[Omega]p^2)y[x] == -((\[Omega]p^2)*
          PDF[NormalDistribution[x0, \[CurlyEpsilon]], x])/(4*Pi), 
     y[\[CurlyEpsilon]] == 1, y[5] == 0}, 
    y, {x, \[CurlyEpsilon], 5}, {\[Omega]p}, 
    MaxStepSize -> \[CurlyEpsilon], MaxSteps -> Infinity]];
Plot[sol[\[Omega][1]][x], {x, 1/1000, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1/1000, 5}, {0, 0.0049}}]
```

But (for example for $\omega[1]$) it gives jump from 1 to 0.004 on next step after x=1/1000

[image]

How can I achieve good correspondence between numerical solution and BCs?

Comment: Your code produces errors: "Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x$82473..."

Comment: @DanielHuber that's because I forgot to write ```x0=0.3```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that OP has encountered has to do with the singular nature of the ODE at $x=0$. The conclusion of this answer is essentially that the simulation is correct (or at least plausible) and that the solution actually has the violent growth that OP has observed. This also means that the issue is not really a Mathematica issue. OP should check if this is really the right problem to solve.

In this answer, I will consider a simpler problem that shows the same issue:
$$x^2 y''(x) + y'(x) = 0 \qquad y(\epsilon) = 1 \qquad y(1) = 0$$
where $0 < \epsilon < 1$ is a parameter. The advantage is that this system can be solved numerically and analytically, which allows us to make a more convincing case. Unlike OPs equation, there is no $\delta$-function here. The reason is that the issue observed by OP has nothing to do with the $\delta$-function, and putting in a $\delta$-function would only be a distraction.

**Numerical solution.** The code is very simple:

```
sol[eps_]:=NDSolveValue[{x^2*y''[x]+y'[x]==0,y[eps]==1,y[1]==0},y[x],{x,eps,1}];
plot[eps_,color_]:=With[{y=sol[eps]},LogLinearPlot[y,{x,eps,1},
                     PlotStyle->color,PlotRange->{{0.001,1},{-0.2,1.2}}]];
```

We plot the solution for five values of $\epsilon$ using

```
Show[{plot[0.005,Magenta],plot[0.02,Brown],plot[0.05,Blue],plot[0.1,Red],plot[0.2,Orange]}]
```

and get this:

[image]

For $\epsilon = 0.005$ the solution almost jumps from $0$ to $1$, similar to what OP has seen. The solutions for bigger values of $\epsilon$ give us some confidence that this is not due to an error in the numerical solution, but that this may be the actual behavior. The next question is, why?

**Analytical solution.** Using

```
DSolveValue[{x^2*y''[x]+y'[x]==0},y[x],x]
```

we get

```
C[2] + C[1] (E^(1/x) x - ExpIntegralEi[1/x])
```

This means that `y1[x_] := 1` is one solution, `y2[x_] := E^(1/x) x - ExpIntegralEi[1/x]` is another solution, and the general solution for $x>0$ is a linear combination of `y1[x]` and `y2[x]`.

Observe that the solution `y2[x]` diverges extremely fast as $x \downarrow 0$. And every solution that is not a constant will have some `y2[x]` in it, and also diverge extremely fast.

Concretely, in our case $y(\epsilon) = 1$ and $y(1) = 0$, which means that the solution cannot simply be a constant, so it will have some `y2[x]` in it, which leads to this extreme growth that we are seeing.

**Discussion.** The extreme growth is due to the $x^2$ term in front of the second derivative. One may want to compare this with other well-known equations such as the [Bessel differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function):
$$x^2 y''(x) + x y'(x) + (x^2-1) y(x) = 0$$
This also has an $x^2$ in front of the second derivative. Two solutions for $x>0$ in this case are `BesselJ[1,x]` and `BesselY[1,x]`, one of which again diverges as $x \downarrow 0$, so the situation is similar to OPs. There is however a difference: In OPs case the divergence of one solution is violent, which is because OPs equation contains a term $y'(x)$, whereas Bessel only contains the milder $xy'(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In fact, the original condition is: y(0)<∞, but I used condition `y[\CurlyEpsilon]==1` instead because I don't know any other methods to implement boundedness of solution at x=0. Can you answer if it is important or not?